# How to find coordinates of vectors [x]e and [y]u in another basis

Tags: linear-algebra, transition-matrix

If we have basis
{e1=(2,-1,-1),e2=(3,1,1),e3=(-2,-1,-2)}
and basis
{u1=(-3,1,2),u2=(1,1,3),u3=(-2,-2,-1)}
The question is prove that e1,e2,e3 and u1,u2,u3 forms basis of R³
And find the transition matrix from first basis to the second one.
And if we have the coordinates of vectors [X]e=(-2,2,-2) and [Y]u=(2,-1,1) in one basis, find the coordinates of these vectors in the another basis.
I proved correctly and I found the transition matrix, but how can i find the coordinates of vectors [X]e and [Y]u in another basis?
I think that I should use the transition matrix.
Please can any one give a hint
Hint the transition matrix I got:
Transition matrix C=B.A^-1, where B is the matrix of vectors u1,u2,u3 as a columns of thier coordinates, and A is the matrix of coordinates of vectors e1,e2,e3

(-2/5  8/5  3/5)

(2/5  -8/5  7/5)

(1         1       -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. If $M_{E\to U}$ is the transition matrix from $E$ to $U$, and you have the coordinates of $X$ in the base $E$, to get them on the base $U$ you just need to multiply
$$[X]_U=M_{E\to U}\cdot[X]_E.$$
To do the reverse change of basis, you just need the transition matrix from $U$ to $E$, but that's nothing but the inverse of the previous matrix:
$$M_{U\to E}=M_{E\to U}^{-1}.$$

Just to clarify, I am guessing that you are calculating $M_{E\to U}$ as a matrix whose **columns** are the coordinates of $e_i$ in the $U$ basis. Note that the coordinate vectors $[X]_E$ and $[Y]_U$ must be written in **column** form so you be able to make the product.

You could also have calculated $M_{E\to U}$ as a matrix whose **rows** are the coordinates of $e_i$ in the $U$ basis. Then, the vectors in the product would be written in **row** form and the product would be:
$$[X]_U=[X]_E\cdot M_{E\to U}$$

Comment: Thank you, Can you please, write the answer?

Comment: I think it would be nice if you wrote the transition matrix that you got, and we can work it from there.

Comment: I edited the question